# Paste the value of a cell in all the blank cells below, then move onto a new value to repeat the process in Excel VBA Macros

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do something similar to a question I found here:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36687740/copy-non-blank-cell-into-cell-below-repeat-for-each-blank-cell)

Basically it's trying to paste the first value it scrolls through in all the blank spaces below it, until there's another value, which gets pasted into all the blank spaces below it too, repeating the process until it reaches the cell that has a row containing the last entry of data.

I want to be able to tailor it to my excel sheet, by creating a macro for it. Here's the best suited code so far:

```
Sub fillBlanks()
  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
      With .Offset(0, -1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
      End With
      With .Offset(0, -1)
        .Value = .Value
      End With
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

I can't seem to find a way to adapt it to searching through column B only and ignore pasting the value if there aren't any blank spaces below it.

[image: Image Here]

In this image the values go 0004,0002,0004. I want to avoid having the macro pasting the 0002 value in the second 0004 value.

Please may I get some help?

Thanks,

Aydan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a suggestion other than what is listed in your related link; you can find the last row of the sheet and loop through the cells in column B, whilst comparing the value.

```
Dim i as Integer, LR as Long

LR=Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to LR

If Cells(i,2).Value="" Then
    Cells(i-1,2).Copy Cells(i,2)
    Else
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: I received an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method." on this line of code: `Cells(i - 1, 2).Copy Cells(i, 2).Paste`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was away from my computer :) Thankyou very much!

Comment: @AydanHowell no worries; glad it worked out for you!

Comment: Yes it was a very useful fix, managed to automate something that would have taken weeks to do manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the range you need, then running this:

Sub RepeatTitle()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim RNG As Range
    Dim Str As String
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim K As Integer


    Set RNG = Selection
    K = 1
    J = 1

    For K = 1 To RNG.Columns.Count
        For J = 1 To RNG.Rows.Count
            If RNG.Cells(J, K) = "" Then
                If J = 1 Then
                    RNG.Cells(J, K) = ""
                Else
                    RNG.Cells(J, K) = RNG.Cells(J - 1, K)
                End If
            End If
        Next J
    Next K

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

This will work for any J * K selection.

Comment: Are J and K, x and y values?

Comment: Updated to say J and K now, but yes

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to do anything when I paste this. Also, isn't your code decreasing the x value, not the y value?

Comment: It isn't really x and y, it is Cells(row, column), and are you selecting(highlighting) the range to run on before running the code?

Answer (score 0):

This code makes use of `FIND` and `FILLDOWN` to quickly find the next row containing a value and then filling everything inbetween:

```
Public Sub FillGaps()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rFindCells As Range
    Dim rFillColumn As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim rPrevious As Range

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set rFillColumn = wrkSht.Columns(2)

    With rFillColumn
        Set rFindCells = .Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not rFindCells Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAddress = rFindCells.Address
            Do
                Set rPrevious = rFindCells
                Set rFindCells = .FindNext(rFindCells)

                If rFindCells.Row <> rPrevious.Row + 1 And rFindCells.Row > rPrevious.Row Then
                    wrkSht.Range(rPrevious, rFindCells.Offset(-1)).FillDown
                End If

            Loop While rFindCells.Address <> sFirstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```